# how to create <ol> <li> structure as per below Json data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Create Dynamic structure for OL LI based on below JSON and also provide JSON data and OL LI structure format also. so please check this.

Json Data format is :

```js
let dataArray = [{
  parent1: {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Parent',
    parentId: null,
    children: [{
      child: {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Child-1',
        parentId: 1,
        children: [{
          child: {
            id: 4,
            title: 'Child-1.1',
            parentId: 2,
            children: [{
              child: {
                id: 6,
                title: 'Child-1.1.1',
                parentId: 4,
                children: []
              }
            }]
          }
        }]
      }
    }, {
      child: {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Child-2',
        parentId: 1,
        children: [{
          child: {
            id: 5,
            title: 'Child-2.1',
            parentId: 3,
            children: []
          }
        }]
      }
    }, ]
  }
}]
```

For Sample Example OL LI format :

```
    <ol class="organizational-chart">
        <li>
            <div>Parent</div>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <div>Child-1</div>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            <div>Child-1.1</div>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>Child-2</div>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            <div>Child-2.1</div>
                            <ol>
                                <li>
                                    <div>Child-2.1.</div>
                                    <ol>
                                        <li>
                                            <div>Child-2.1.1</div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ol>
                                </li>
                            </ol>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
        </li>
    </ol>
```

How to create above `<ol><li>` structure as per below JSON?

Comment: Use for loops to iterate through each object and create elements appropriately.

Comment: try writing some code to do what you want. If it's not working as desired, post it in your question and we can help refine it to get it working

Answer (score 1):

```js
var dataArray = [{
  parent1: {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Parent',
    parentId: null,
    children: [{
      child: {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Child-1',
        parentId: 1,
        children: [{
          child: {
            id: 4,
            title: 'Child-1.1',
            parentId: 2,
            children: [{
              child: {
                id: 6,
                title: 'Child-1.1.1',
                parentId: 4,
                children: []
              }
            }]
          }
        }]
      }
    }, {
      child: {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Child-2',
        parentId: 1,
        children: [{
          child: {
            id: 5,
            title: 'Child-2.1',
            parentId: 3,
            children: []
          }
        }]
      }
    }, ]
  }
}]

function li(){
  return document.createElement("li");
}
function ol(){
  return document.createElement("ol");
}
function div(){
  return document.createElement("div");
}

function addList(rawData, node){
   let parent = ol();
   const {parent1, parent: parent2, child} = rawData; //since data is not defined, so taking these keys as per data
   
   //taking data
   let data;
   if(parent1)  data = parent1;
   else if(parent2) data = parent2;
   else data = child;
   
   node.appendChild(parent); //append parent node to the grandParent passed
   parent.innerHTML = `<div>${data.title}</div>`; //add title div
   
   data.children?.forEach((ele) => { //loop over children
      let child = li(); 
      parent.appendChild(child); //append li tag
      addList(ele, child); //run recursion for adding children on this li component
   });
}

dataArray.forEach((data) => addList(data, document.getElementById("root")))
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use loops and recurrency for creating the nested list. This is a pseudo-code that you should "translate" into proper javascript.

```
dataArray.forEach(rootNode => {
  const element = createList(rootNode);
  document.body.appendChild(element);
});

// create elements
function createList(node) {
  const ol = cretateOlElement(node);
  node.children.forEach(listItem => {
    const li = createListItem(ol, listItem); // recursively check for children and call createList again
    ol.appendChild(li);
  });

  return ol;
}
```

Comment: Thanks its true but in ol can contain seperate li for each child like Child1 and Child2 both in seperate li tag inside one ol so please give me suggestion for it.